# Udacity Ice Cream Quiz - Javascript statement/condition

Tags: javascript, variables, boolean

Need some help with a quiz below.

```js
/*
 * Programming Quiz: Ice Cream (3-6)
 *
 * Write a single if statement that logs out the message:
 * 
 * "I'd like two scoops of __________ ice cream in a __________ with __________."
 * 
 * ...only if:
 *   - flavor is "vanilla" or "chocolate"
 *   - vessel is "cone" or "bowl"
 *   - toppings is "sprinkles" or "peanuts"
 *
 * We're only testing the if statement and your boolean operators. 
 * It's okay if the output string doesn't match exactly.
 */

// change the values of `flavor`, `vessel`, and `toppings` to test your code
var flavor = "strawberry";
var vessel = "hand";
var toppings = "cookies";

// Add your code here
if (flavor === "vanilla" || "chocolate" && vessel === "cone" || "bowl" && toppings === "prinkles" || "peanuts"){
    console.log("I'd like two scoops of " + flavor + " ice cream in a " + vessel + " with " + toppings + ".");
}
else {
    
}
```

I can't seem to find a way how to print the statement **only if** the conditions are met. At this point, whenever I use a variable that's **not** defined in the condition; it prints out in the console anyway.
I would like to find a way to prevent that.
Hopefully it all makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Look into `&&` (and) and `||` (if). But we're not here to make your homework for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the condition check like `=== 'str1' || 'str2` which is not correct.

You can explicitly specify all the conditions so that it will be clear for the understanding.

```
if ((flavor === "vanilla" || flavor === "chocolate") && (vessel === "cone" || vessel === "bowl") && (toppings === "prinkles" || toppings === "peanuts")){
```

Comment: actually `=== 'str1' || 'str2'` can be use but you need a bracket for it `=== ('str1' || 'str2')`

Comment: Wasn't still working until I've added another set of brackets around the whole if statement. Thanks! :)

Comment: Basically ended up doing this instead and everything went fine          if (((flavor === "vanilla") || (flavor === "chocolate"))
    && ((vessel === "cone") || (vessel === "bowl"))
    && ((toppings === "sprinkles") || (toppings === "peanuts")))

Comment: @Dean, "=== ('str1' || 'str2')" is not the correct way to do the comparison. The best way is to use includes, which was mentioned by fcalderan.

Answer (score 1):

Try like so:

```
var flavor = "vanilla";
var vessel = "bowl";
var toppings = "peanuts";

if (
    ["vanilla","chocolate"].includes(flavor)
    && ["cone", "bowl"].includes(vessel)
    && ["sprinkles", "peanuts"].includes(toppings)) {

       console.log("I'd like two scoops of %s ice cream in a %s with %s toppings.", 
                    flavor, vessel, toppings);
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dejrxB?editors=0010)

---

Reference about `includes()` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Appreciate the code and the link. I'll have to research further about the includes() via the link provided. Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var flavor = "chocolate"||"vanilla";
var vessel = "bowl"||"cone";
var toppings = "sprinkles"||"peanuts";



if(( flavor==="chocolate"|| flavor==="vanilla" ) && (vessel==="bowl"||vessel==="cone") && (toppings==="peanuts" ||toppings==="sprinkles")){
    console.log("I'd like two scoops of " + flavor + " ice cream in a " + vessel + " with " + toppings);
    
}
```

---